# cPanel Parked Domains Not returning array

Tags: php, cpanel, cpanel-xmlapi

A password was changed and cPanel broke. Fixed the password and it's still broken! I have to iterate over parked domains. I've verified the user / password combination is correct via PuTTY.

```
<?php
include_once('cpanel_api_xml.php');
$domain = 'example.com';
$pass = '';//etc
$user = '';//etc
$xmlapi = new xmlapi('127.0.0.1');
$xmlapi->password_auth($user,$pass);
$domains_parked = $xmlapi->listparkeddomains($user);

foreach ($domains_parked as $k1=>$v1)
{
 if ($v1->domain == $domain) {$return = true; break;}
}
?>
```

That code generates the following error:

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Apparently `$domains_parked` is not even set! I've spent time looking at the function being called so without dumping all 86KB here is the cleaned up version of `$xmlapi->listparkeddomains`:

```
<?php
public function listparkeddomains($username, $domain = null)
{
 $args = array();
 if (!isset($username))
 {
  error_log("listparkeddomains requires that a user is passed to it");
  return false;
 }

 if (isset($domain))
 {
  $args['regex'] = $domain;
  return $this->api2_query($username, 'Park', 'listparkeddomains', $args);
 }

 return $this->api2_query($username, 'Park', 'listparkeddomains');
}
?>
```

I don't know what they're doing with setting a variable as the second parameter. I've called this function with and without and tested the reaction with a simple `mail()`.

Next I tried calling the API in a more direct fashion:

```
$xmlapi->api2_query($username, 'Park', 'listparkeddomains')
```

*That also* does not work. Okay, let's try some really raw output testing:

```
echo "1:\n";
print_r($xmlapi);
echo "2:\n";
print_r($xmlapi->api2_query($user, 'Park', 'listparkeddomains'));
echo "3:\n";
$domains_parked = $xmlapi->listparkeddomains($user);
print_r($domains_parked);
die();
```

That outputs the following:

> 1: xmlapi Object (
>
> ```
> [debug:xmlapi:private] => 
>
> [host:xmlapi:private] => 127.0.0.1
>
> [port:xmlapi:private] => 4099
>
> [protocol:xmlapi:private] => https
>
> [output:xmlapi:private] => simplexml
>
> [auth_type:xmlapi:private] => pass
>
> [auth:xmlapi:private] => <pass>
>
> [user:xmlapi:private] => <user>
>
> [http_client:xmlapi:private] => curl ) 2: 3:
> ```

I have never encountered such fragile code though I have no choice but to use it. Some help please?

Answer (score 1):

So cPanel version 74 killed off the whole XML API and *it doesn't frigin tell you with any error messages*. I can not objectively say in the least that cPanel provides a stable platform to build anything reliable upon. You can either intentionally gimp your server from automatically updating (and potentially miss out on security updates) or every so X iterations of time completely rewrite the code again...and again...and again.